# jquery validation input field text with certain string on certain dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Let say I have a text input field and I want to make sure that user can only press submit button/go through the form when the input field receives certain text in certain dates....

Is that posible using jquery validation plugin

I have set up a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ecj6J/3/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="submitDetails" action="#" method="POST" id="submitDetails">

      <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
        <label class="col-xs-5 control-label" for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
          <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" class="form-control input-md"  maxlength="80"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-12 mySubmitButton">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block" title="SUBMIT" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

js validation code so far

```
  $(document).ready(function () {


  $('#submitDetails').validate({
    // 1. validation rules.
    rules: {
      firstName: {
        required: true,
      }
    },
    messages: {
      firstName: "Please enter your first name"

  });

///execute when submit button is clicked
$("#submit").click(function () {
});  
});
```

**So basically, when user presses text "ABCD" on day 1, he is allowed to process or else an error message will show up. Similarly, when user inputs text "EFGH" on day 2, he is allowed to process or else he is shown an error field text message.**

Comment: how do you know whether it is day 1 or day 2

Comment: Actually day 1 or day2 are just arbitary terms I am using. I already know it.. .it is part of a larger paroject I am working on. So lets say if it is 16th December (today), it is day 1. If it is 17th December it is day 2.....In other words, I already know the dates for day 1 and day 2. Thanks

Comment: and you know the needed text also right

Comment: Yes I know the needed text too. That is correct.

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bSP94/3/

Comment: YEs something like that. Thanks. However, I have an added request :). Rather than saying day = 1 , is it possible somehow to include date range as in day = 16/12/2013 - 22/12/2013.... So lets say, this week day will be 16/12/2013 - 22/12/2013 and next week day will be 23/12/2013 - 29/12/2013. ? And user's computer date is then checked and validated and the correct date is taken from the range?

Comment: I have update your jsfiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/bSP94/7/  .. However I need it such atht if the date is between a particular range.. so if day 1 is between 16th - 22, day 2 can be anything between 23rd to 29th etc....how to put range therE?

Comment: Thanks I think I have it solved as in http://jsfiddle.net/bSP94/11/  . Thank you for your help. Please add your solution below as your answer so I can mark as your answer as solution. Cheers